# When I try sudo gem install json I get the following error

Tags: json, ruby, macos, rubygems

I need to install the JSON gem to start my app but I get the error below whenever I try to install the json gem.  Can anyone help me out.  I'm using rails 2.2.2 and gems 1.3.1.

```
Arions-macbook-pro:.ssh arion$ sudo gem install json
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb install json
can't find header files for ruby.


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.1.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.1.4/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Have you installed ruby-dev ?

Comment: How do you install ruby-dev on a mac?  is it a port or a gem or something like that?

Comment: Be careful installing/changing the Apple-installed Ruby. Unless you're sure you know what you're doing, you're better off installing RVM or rbenv, and letting it manage the sandboxed Ruby.

Comment: If installing xcode command line tools doesn't fix the issue, and `make` can't find `gcc` see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12256616/637283

Answer (score 22):

With Mavericks, you can solve this problem by installing the Xcode Command Line Tools from the command line like this:

`xcode-select --install`

Update:
Don't forget to accept the license agreement after you install or update:

`sudo xcodebuild -license`

Comment: It's is required to restart your macOS, then run your command.

Answer (score 13):

If you have this problem:

```
ERROR:  Error installing json:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

and you are using a Mac with OS X (tested with 10.8.1 Mountain Lion), you need to download Xcode from the Mac App Store (or from developer.apple.com if you have a dev account - it's free BTW and you can download a DMG installer)

The latest Xcode versions (I'm using Xcode 4.4.1) does NOT include command line tools. Now you need to install this additional package inside Xcode. Once done, your problem is fixed.

To do that, open Xcode, go to Preferences > Downloads > Components. Install "Command Line Tools". You're done. Now you can install the json Ruby gem.

[image]

Comment: To get Command line dev tools and avoid installing Xcode: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19532316/637283

Answer (score 10):

You are missing the ruby development headers. To install these on an OS like ubuntu you should use:

```
aptitude install ruby1.8-dev
```

Comment: Im using a mac... do I still just need to install ruby-dev?

Comment: -1 `aptitude` won't help since it's not installed on Mac OS X.

Comment: The question is obviously about Mac OS X, so, your answer is not relevant.

Comment: After installing ruby-dev for my current version (the version cited in your json-install error), the json installation succeeded for me.
$ sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
$ sudo gem install json -v '1.8.1'

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Guys seriously, it's just an example for a Debian-like OS, simply adapt the command to your system (e.g. `yum install ruby-devel` or whatever).

Answer (score 4):

The ruby headers don’t come installed with the base ruby install with Mac OS X. These can been found on Mac OS X Install Disc 2 by installing the XCode Tools.

Once installed, all was well!

**UPDATE** As of at least OS X 10.7.3 this is no longer a problem, it "just works"

```
MacBook-Pro:tmp$ sudo gem install json
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed json-1.6.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for json-1.6.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for json-1.6.5...
MacBook-Pro:tmp$ uname -a
```

Comment: Um, not true.  Perhaps it was something else that caused this to "just work" for you.

Answer (score 3):

Installing Xcode command line tools... should fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

A simple [google search](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en-us&q=can't+find+header+files+for+ruby) reveals this:

If you get the can't find header files for ruby error message when trying to build an extension or a gem, it means that Ruby cannot locate its header files.

Header files are not delivered by default with Mac OS X, you need to install the Xcode Tools package after the installation. You can find it in the Optional Installs / Xcode Tools directory on the Leopard DVD.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out certain gems require some ruby header files to install properly. These header files **do not** ship with Lion (OSX 10.7).

It also turns out Xcode 4 (latest release) **also does not** install these header files. I tried this.

**Solution -** Assuming you are on Mac OS X (you appear to be based on the terminal output). To get it working I installed gcc *with some developer tools* from the following page

- Visit https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer
- Scroll down to the README and download the appropriate package (for OSX 10.7 or 10.6)
- Open the `.pkg` file and run the installer.

You should be able to install the gems now, either with `gem install` or `bundle install`.

**Overhead** If you are worried about the other junk this comes with, here is a summary.

- `gcc` - useful
- `make` - useful
- `clang` - useful for ObjectiveC
- Developer CLI Tools (purge, etc) - useful?
- DevSDK (headers, etc) - **what you need**

Answer (score 0):

If you use homebrew, run `brew doctor`. You might find out that the required gcc libraries for compilation are outdated and/or missing.

```
Warning: No compiler found in /usr/bin!
Warning: Your Xcode (4.2) is outdated

checking for gcc... /Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/freexl-apNF/freexl-1.0.0d':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

For Lion and Mountain Lion users, Apple now provides an official Command Line Tools for Xcode package that you can install without needing to install Xcode itself! You can download it from Apple's developer site https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action. If you still need gcc-4.2, and you use Homebrew, you can install it using the apple-gcc42 package from homebrew/dupes.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

Here is my adventures (hope it will be useful):

To fix it I've done many manipulations :-)

I'm using Fedora Core.
I've fixed it this way:

I've installed rails-devel:

> sudo yum install rails-devel

tried again:

> sudo gem install rails

but I've got another problem:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing rails:     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>     /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb creating Makefile
> ```
>
> make gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-linux
>   -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-linux -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-strict-aliasing  -fPIC  -O3 -Wall  -c parser.c
>   **make: gcc: Command not found**

So I've installed GCC:

> sudo yum install gcc

tried again:

> sudo gem install rails

Now I've got another problem ))) :

> Installing ri documentation for json-1.6.3... ERROR:  While generating
>   documentation for json-1.6.3 ... MESSAGE:   no such file to load --
>   irb/slex ... RDOC args: --ri --op
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/json-1.6.3/ri --title JSON implemention for
>   Ruby --main README.rdoc ext/json/ext ext lib README.rdoc --title
>   json-1.6.3 Documentation --quiet

So installed ruby-irb:

> sudo yum install ruby-irb

tried again:

> sudo gem install rails
>
> **Successfully installed rails-3.1.3**

That's all )))

Comment: You installed Fedora Core on a Mac OS box just to install Ruby? I don't think you read the question well.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution:

```
rvm gem install json -v=xxx
```

My setup:

```
OSX Lion
ruby-1.9.3
rvm
gcc-4.2 #=> honestly haven't seen that it's been used
```