# MySQL Install: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems

I'm trying to get MySQL installed to the latest version due to some installation going wrong somewhere along the line.  I run the command `gem install mysql` and I receive the following:

> Building native extensions.  This
>   could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing mysql:     ERROR: Failed to
>   build gem native extension.
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
>   extconf.rb extconf.rb:4: warning:
>   Insecure world writable dir /usr/bin
>   in PATH, mode 040777 extconf.rb:4:
>   warning: Insecure world writable dir
>   /usr/bin in PATH, mode 040777
>   extconf.rb:7: warning: Insecure world
>   writable dir /usr/bin in PATH, mode
>   040777 mkmf.rb can't find header files
>   for ruby at
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out

I've searched, and tried a whole host of things, from installing specific versions to trying to reinstall ruby without any luck.

Any ideas where I may be going wrong?

I'm trying to get MySQL installed to the latest version due to some installation going wrong somewhere along the line.  I run the command `gem install mysql` and I receive the following:

> Building native extensions.  This
>   could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing mysql:     ERROR: Failed to
>   build gem native extension.
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
>   extconf.rb extconf.rb:4: warning:
>   Insecure world writable dir /usr/bin
>   in PATH, mode 040777 extconf.rb:4:
>   warning: Insecure world writable dir
>   /usr/bin in PATH, mode 040777
>   extconf.rb:7: warning: Insecure world
>   writable dir /usr/bin in PATH, mode
>   040777 mkmf.rb can't find header files
>   for ruby at
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out

I've searched, and tried a whole host of things, from installing specific versions to trying to reinstall ruby without any luck.

Any ideas where I may be going wrong?

**EDIT**: I installed XCode off my Snow Leopard DVD and the error just changed slightly to the following:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
>     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>   extconf.rb:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/bin in PATH, mode 040777
>   extconf.rb:4: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/bin in PATH, mode 040777
>   extconf.rb:7: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/bin in PATH, mode 040777
>   extconf.rb:17: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/bin in PATH, mode 040777
>   checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
>   checking for main() in -lm... yes
>   checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
>   checking for main() in -lz... yes
>   checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
>   checking for main() in -lsocket... no
>   checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
>   checking for main() in -lnsl... no
>   checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
>   checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
>   checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
>   *** extconf.rb failed ***
>   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
>   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
>   details.  You may need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>       --with-opt-dir
>       --without-opt-dir
>       --with-opt-include
>       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>       --with-opt-lib
>       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>       --with-make-prog
>       --without-make-prog
>       --srcdir=.
>       --curdir
>       --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
>       --with-mysql-config
>       --without-mysql-config
>       --with-mysql-dir
>       --without-mysql-dir
>       --with-mysql-include
>       --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
>       --with-mysql-lib
>       --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
>       --with-mysqlclientlib
>       --without-mysqlclientlib
>       --with-mlib
>       --without-mlib
>       --with-mysqlclientlib
>       --without-mysqlclientlib
>       --with-zlib
>       --without-zlib
>       --with-mysqlclientlib
>       --without-mysqlclientlib
>       --with-socketlib
>       --without-socketlib
>       --with-mysqlclientlib
>       --without-mysqlclientlib
>       --with-nsllib
>       --without-nsllib
>       --with-mysqlclientlib
>       --without-mysqlclientlib
>       --with-mygcclib
>       --without-mygcclib
>       --with-mysqlclientlib
>       --without-mysqlclientlib
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
>   Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out

doing "which mysql" on the command line returns nothing, which means it's not recognizing it.  I also installed the MySQL system preferences option, and I can't stop MySQL from running.  Now I'm completely stuck as what to do!

**EDIT EDIT**

I've just completely reinstalled MySQL using this guide http://hivelogic.com/articles/installing-mysql-on-mac-os-x

Unfortunately this didn't work either, I still receive the same errors.  I can't even do mysql -uroot at the command line, I get the error of:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

So I think I've tried everything.

**SOLVED*

Sorry guys, the reason for this not working was because of the MySQL paths.  I've blogged on it here: http://www.kieransenior.co.uk/2010/02/mysql-cant-connect-using-ruby-on-rails-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

[Installing the mysql gem on OSX](http://trevoke.net/blog/2009/04/17/installing-the-mysql-gem-on-osx/)

in a terminal.. First do a ‘locate mysql_config’ **and then replace the path in the following command with where that file is**.

```
$ sudo gem install mysql -- —–with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
Building native extensions. This could take a while…
Successfully installed mysql-2.7
1 gem installed
```

Comment: I installed XAMPP for OSX, so my command was: ```gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql_config```. No sudo required!

Comment: Just fyi.  I was still not able to install, but then I realized that /usr/local/mysql/bin was not on my PATH env variable.  Once I got that on my PATH, I was able to install it without a problem.

Comment: I had to `sudo locate mysql_config` to get the config paths. Otherwise, it return the message: `WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist. ...`

Comment: I had to install xcode command line tools before this answer would ultimately work for me. See this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761521/when-i-try-sudo-gem-install-json-i-get-the-following-error/19532316#19532316  and then try `sudo gem install mysql1 etc` like in this answer :)

Comment: @JoshBurson If you want a _complete_ guide to installing mysql from scratch on OSX, I think it's a wholly different story.

Comment: Absolutely. I wasn't, however, installing from scratch. I commented to help others who may be running into issues like I was.

Answer (score 175):

On Debian (or Ubuntu) systems, just install libmysqlclient-dev package using:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

and then:

```
gem install mysql
```

It will be installed without any error.

Comment: Great! Worked in Ubuntu 14.10 64 bits

Comment: Worked for me too, Ubuntu 14.4 LTS trusty

Answer (score 17):

First of all you need to differentiate between the MySQL as Server, MySQL as Client and the Ruby bindings to MySQL.

I'm not familiar with Mac, but for *nix OS you need to install MySQL through your package manager. To get the Ruby bindings installed with

```
gem install mysql
```

you need the development headers of ruby (in Ubuntu it is the package ruby-dev) and the development headers of the MySQL-Client (currently `libmysqlclient16-dev` in Ubuntu). I don't know if they are named different on Mac, but after you got those installed the Ruby bindings should install without any error.

Comment: Indubitably, there is a multi-packaged version which does both.  I've gone through this process as well.  I think you're right, I do need to differentiate between the two as this has been mainly my problem.  Another option, perhaps, is to install MAMP and use that? What would I need then?

Comment: MAMP stands for Mac, Apache, MySQL, Php.
So you would still need a MySQL-Server and in addition Apache 2, and the php libraries for apache. I'm not sure if you can just select MAMP in your package manager and it will install all required files. Maybe a Mac user could help you out there.

Comment: Indeed it would fall short of the need for MAMP, but it was just an easy way to serve up a MySQL instance.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed on Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev` and `sudo gem install mysql`. Thanks!

Comment: yep, this worked: 'sudo apt-get install ruby-dev libmysqlclient16-dev' then 'sudo gem install mysql'

Comment: Thanks Aurril - ruby-dev is what was missing in my case!

Answer (score 9):

A number of people found [this post](http://blog.bmn.name/2008/02/rails-gem-install-mysql-throws-error-extconfrb-failed/) helpful.

Also, I needed to do first type this:

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

and then:

```
gem install mysql
```

For some people you may need to type:

```
gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/mysql_config
```

Comment: Dude, If I could give you 2 up I would! Although is good to note that this yum command may only be useful with some flavors of LINUX. In my case CentOS 6.0

Answer (score 5):

on OSX mountain Lion: If you have `brew` installed, then `brew install mysql` and follow the `instructions` on creating a test database with mysql on your machine.
You don't have to go all the way through, I didn't need to
After I did that I was able to bundle install and rake.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me! Cheers mate!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar experience, so here are the things that I tried

Firstly, I tried to install  mysql's required packages by running the command below in my terminal

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libmysqlclient-dev
```

Secondly, I tried updating rubygems on my system by running the command below in my terminal

```
sudo gem update --system
```

But I was still experiencing the same issue.

**Here’s what worked for me**

After much research I realized that I was using an almost out-of-date version of the mysql gem. I simply needed to use the **mysql2** gem ([mysql2 gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2))and not the **mysql** gem, so I fixed it by running the command below in my terminal

```
gem install mysql2
```

This worked fine for me. Before running the last command, ensure that you've ran the first and second commands to be sure that everything is fine on your system.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: this command saved me ```gem install mysql2``` thank you

Answer (score 3):

In order to resolve

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
>   error for mysql2,
>
> I think **libmysql-ruby** got changed with
>    **ruby-mysql**

Simply try with following commands,

`sudo apt-get install ruby-mysql`

& then

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

I had also forgotten to actually *install* MySQL in the first place. Following this guide helped a lot.

http://www.djangoapp.com/blog/2011/07/24/installation-of-mysql-server-on-mac-os-x-lion/

As well as adding these lines to my .profile:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
alias mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
alias mysqladmin=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to reinstall the latest version of xcode / dev. tools for snow leopard - this should fix your errors

Comment: This was one of the first things I did.  Snow Leopard's version of XCode is installed on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

if you are installing from source here is a tutorial.would be happy if it helps http://raihan90.blogspot.com/2009/03/mysql-step-by-step-hacking-into-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

Attention: You need to specify -- key, and than --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

Comment: Again, this answer is floating in many-a-place.  In my instance, it doesn't work.  Plus, mysql didn't exist for me in /usr/local/ I believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Percona Mysql server

$ yum install Percona-Server-devel-55

$ gem install mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
yum -y install gcc mysql-devel ruby-devel rubygems
gem install mysql2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Ubuntu OS need to install library for mysql client
`sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

After That just install `bundle` or `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

While these answers pointed me in the right direction, on Alpine linux the package I needed was `mariadb-dev`, eg. run `apk add mariadb-dev` *before* the `gem install mysql` command.