# issue in installing mysql2 gem with rails3 on mac

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

```
 Installing mysql2 (0.2.6) with native extensions /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework  /Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6 for inspection.  
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `build_extensions'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:198:in `install'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:96:in `install'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:226:in `install'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/bin/bundle:13
from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/bundle:19
```

**EDIT**

```
  Mohit-Jains-MacBook-Pro:casecreed mohit$ locate mysql_config
 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_config
 /usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql_config
 /usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64/man/man1/mysql_config.1
```

and after doing what u suggested...

ie

```
     sudo gem install mysql2 -- –with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64/bin/mysql_config
```

here is the error..

```
    Mohit-Jains-MacBook-Pro:casecreed mohit$ rake db:create
    (in /Users/mohit/projects/casecreed)
    rake aborted!
    dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib
      Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
      Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    /Users/mohit/projects/casecreed/Rakefile:4
    (See full trace by running task with --trace
```

**EDIT2**

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33z69.png) of whole process after answer was modified..

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
Couldn't create database for {"reconnect"=>false, "encoding"=>"utf8", "username"=>"root", "adapter"=>"mysql2", "database"=>"the_casecreed_test", "host"=>"localhost", "pool"=>5, "password"=>nil}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_unicode_ci
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
Couldn't create database for {"reconnect"=>false, "encoding"=>"utf8", "username"=>"root", "adapter"=>"mysql2", "database"=>"the_casecreed_development", "host"=>"localhost", "pool"=>5, "password"=>nil}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_unicode_ci
```

**EDIT3**

[development.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4qyR.png)

**EDIT4**

Even not able to connect to mysql.

[Check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PelPP.png).

**EDIT5**

This is the solution but i am not able to understand, why mysql server was not starting..

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBqsT.png)

Comment: Looks like you are missing ruby development package. Alternatively you can try http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack

Comment: I highly recommend you install ruby with RVM and mysql with homebrew. This is simple, this works.

Comment: @apneadiving whats the need for that? i just want to instal mysql2 gem thats it. Its working perfecltly on my linux machine. just bought a macbook pro and not able to install on it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following, which seems to have [worked for others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167598/mysql-install-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension):

1. From the Terminal, run `locate mysql_config` and identify the path to the `mysql_config` binary
2. Use that path in the following command to install the gem:`sudo gem install mysql2 -- –with-mysql-config=/path/you/identified/above/mysql_config`

[Edit]

In response to the new error, e.g.:

```
Mohit-Jains-MacBook-Pro:casecreed mohit$ rake db:create
(in /Users/mohit/projects/casecreed)
rake aborted!
dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
/Users/mohit/projects/casecreed/Rakefile:4
(See full trace by running task with --trace
```

I believe this is due to mysql2 not using the full path to libmysqlclient.16.dylib. Others have had luck with:

```
sudo install_name_tool -change libmysqlclient.16.dylib /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

However, be sure to replace `/usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib` with the path to your own `libmysqlclient.16.dylib`. I'm not positive what it would be, but you may be able to find it with `locate` (if not, check around in the `lib` directory for `/usr/local/mysql-5.5.9-osx10.6-x86_64`).

Comment: @Brandon Tilley  cool.. we are seems quit clone.. can u check the edit2 part.. added a screenshot..Thanks a lot man...

Comment: That's interesting; I know this sounds silly, but can you double check your `config/database.yml` to make sure there's no "socket" entry in your `development` section?

Comment: @Brandon Tilley  ya there is nothing like that... check edit3. Uff.. I think i made a mistake by buyin this mac.. Ubuntu is so good.. I thnk i should move back and throw this bloody machine..

Comment: @Brandon Tilley check edit3 and edit4.. i am not able to connect to mysql using command line.

Comment: @Brandon Tilley something worked, Please check edit5. Can u help me whats happening. and why?

Comment: I think that MySQL is starting by default using a command that's placing a connect socket somewhere else on the system. Do a fresh restart (or however you need to reset the system to a "default" MySQL state) and run `ps aux | grep mysql` and see if you see a mysqld line with the `--socket` option on it. If you do, you can either modify `database.yml` to point to it (`socket: /path/to/real/mysqld.sock`) or you can create a symlink to it in `/tmp/mysql.sock`. When you ran mysqld_safe it ran w/o socket opt. Don't give up! Although I have to say I never had this much trouble w/ MySQL on my Mac :)

Comment: "I think i made a mistake by buyin this mac.. Ubuntu is so good.. I thnk i should move back and throw this bloody machine." ... or at least give it back to Mohit Jain ;-P

Comment: @brandon perfect. thanks ur help plus google.com solved the things.. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 3):

download 64 bit from here and then try to install mysql2 gem

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

it will work..

Answer (score 0):

Try installing mysql from macports

```
sudo ports install mysql5
```

It took ages to complete, but once done run

```
gem install mysql2
```

and everything should work just fine