# Installing mysql2-0.2.6 on a Mac

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, installation

I'm having trouble finding good instructions on how to install mysql2-0.2.6 and have it up and running for a ruby on rails application. Could anyone please break down this process?

When I try to install the gem, I get this error:

```
Installing mysql2 (0.2.6) /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:574:in `initialize': Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/.gitignore (Errno::EACCES)
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216563/how-do-you-install-mysql2-0-2-6-on-a-mac-and-connect-it-to-your-ruby-on-rails-app which you posted not long ago. You should clarify your original question instead of creating a new one.

Comment: It was closed for some reason, and I think you posted the wrong link.

Comment: `gem "mysql2", '~> 0.2.6'` in gemfile and then `bundle install`

Comment: Doesn't work. I get this error: Installing mysql2 (0.2.6) /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:574:in `initialize': Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/.gitignore (Errno::EACCES)

Comment: Ideally, you should be using RVM so that you avoid using `sudo gem install ...`. (http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
chmod 666 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/.gitignore
```

Comment: now i get this error: Installing mysql2 (0.2.6) /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1216:in `chmod': Operation not permitted - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/.gitignore (Errno::EPERM)

Comment: What user are you running the commands as? Who owns the file? Can you tell me the output of this command: `ls -l /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/.gitignore`

Comment: I just get this: `-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin  90 Mar  7 02:21 /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/.gitignore`

Comment: Since the file is owned by root, you need to be root to modify its permissions. If the user running gem is not root and it tries to modify the permissions of the file, it will return the error you are getting. Try sudo'ing the gem install.

Answer (score 0):

Locate your path to the mysql_config

```
locate mysql_config
```

Using that path install the gem

```
sudo gem install mysql2 -- –with-mysql-config=/path/to/your/mysql_config
```

Worked for a bunch of [people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024353/issue-in-installing-mysql2-gem-with-rails3-on-mac). Give it a whirl.

EDIT - for missing locate 
make sure you're in the root and then run `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`

Comment: when i run `locate mysql_config` I get this: WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
To create the database, run the following command:

  sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Comment: I ran that command, but I still get the same message when I run `locate mysql_config`

Comment: Ok so now when I follow this there's still an error: ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: hmm... here try downloading a fresh copy from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and then installing the gem

Answer (score 0):

I think this permission error can be fixed by doing:
XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Components tab -> Command Line Tools: press download

Now it should be possible to install through command line.
Regards. Íris

Answer (score 0):

This error is mainly occurred when we install mysql2-0.2.6 with Ruby 1.9.3 version. If you switched to Ruby 2.0, this problem will be solved. Ruby 1.9.3 reached EOL(https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/712) and no support has been given by Ruby core team. Hence there is no use to try with Ruby 1.9.3.