# Really weird error installing mysql2 gem with rails3 on mac

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, installation

I get this error:

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

```
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... no
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

I've tried everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024353/issue-in-installing-mysql2-gem-with-rails3-on-mac) but I still get the error. For some reason when I run `locate mysql_config` this is the result I get:

`/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config`
`/Applications/MAMP/Library/share/man/man1/mysql_config.1`

I tried running `sudo gem install mysql2 -- –with-mysql config=/path/you/identified/above/mysql_config` twice using each path but I still get the error from above. I downloaded a fresh version of MySql and I have Xcode, but I still get these errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the MAMP install the only install of mysql you have? If you've installed it from the mysql package then I think mysql_config will be installed in /usr/local/bin/mysql_config, so you might want to try:

sudo gem install mysql2 -- –with-mysql-config==/usr/local/bin/mysql_config

FYI, the /Applications/MAMP/Library/share/man/man1/mysql_config.1 path is clearly wrong. That's pointing to the man file for mysql_config not the actual executable.

Just to be certain, you did try this right? (exactly as written)

sudo gem install mysql2 -- –with-mysql-config=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config

Also, I'm not sure that mysql packaged with MAMP has the header files you need. You might be best to install mysql from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ and then try to install your gem. In this case I think it will just work.

Comment: sometimes installing a older version of mysql2 works properly.