# converting sqlite to mysql for Ruby on Rails app on macOS Sierr

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

Im following the steps in [Convert a Ruby on Rails app from sqlite to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670154/convert-a-ruby-on-rails-app-from-sqlite-to-mysql) to convert sqlite to mysql for Ruby on Rails app on macOS Sierra but when I get to this step

```
sudo gem install mysql
```

I get an error

```
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Users/abearat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api
/Users/abearat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180322- 
64931-8iib1u.rb extconf.rb
extconf.rb:12: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in 
PATH, mode 040777
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... yes
checking for rb_str_set_len()... yes
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/abearat/.rvm/rubies/ruby- 
2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/abearat/.rvm/rubies/ruby- 
2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api
make "DESTDIR="
compiling mysql.c
mysql.c:588:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 
'my_ulonglong' (aka 'unsigned long long') to 'unsigned int' [- 
Wshorten-64-to-32]
n = mysql_num_rows(res);
  ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/abearat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby- 
2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2333:9: note: expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args0'
                 (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars))
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
10 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [mysql.o] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2
Gem files will remain installed in /Users/abearat/.rvm/rubies/ruby- 
2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/abearat/.rvm/rubies/ruby- 
2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/mysql- 
2.9.1/gem_make.out
```

This is my database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:something
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
development:
   <<: *default
  database: mydb_development
test:
  <<: *default
  database: mydb_test
production:
  <<: *default
  database: borroupdb_production
  username: readit
  password: <%= ENV['READIT_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

In Gemfile i have

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
```

I went here [MySQL Install: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167598/mysql-install-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension) and I tried to follow the steps but I got this message on terminal 
[click here to see image of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrPdZ.png)

Comment: I got it to work cause im running mysql2 the command line should be sudo gem install mysql2

Comment: you should NEVER use sudo in gem instalations , use brew instead first to install dependencies , and after that any gem instalation should be seamless

Comment: thank you for the advice @plombix

Comment: Using sudo when installing gems is a surefire way to mess up the file permissions and will come back to bite you fast.