# Gem mysql2 installation error on ruby1.9.3

Tags: ruby, mysql2, macos-mojave

Just updated to macOS Mojave, reinstalled mysql via brew & downloaded latest xcode 9.2 . While triying to setup a development enviroment for an old rails project, bundle crashes on installation of mysql2 gem. In the beggining i thought it was because latest mysql2 version, is not compatible with ruby 1.9 so i tried:

> gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17'

and i received:

> /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>   checking for ruby/thread.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
>   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
>   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
>   details.  You may need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>     --with-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include
>     --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib
>     --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>     --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog
>     --srcdir=.
>     --curdir
>     --ruby=/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
>   /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
>   You have to install development tools first.
>     from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in`try_cpp'
>     from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
>     from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in`block in checking_for'
>     from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
>     from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in`open'
>     from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
>     from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in`open'
>     from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
>     from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in`checking_for'
>     from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
>     from extconf.rb:9:in`'

copy from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@mailcatcher/gems/mysql2-0.2.18/ext/mysql2/mkmf.log:

> "/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -o conftest -I/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.8.0 -I/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/Users/me/.rvm/usr/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE    -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib -L/Users/me/.rvm/usr/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib     -lruby.1.9.1  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
>   checked program was:
>   /* begin */
>   1: #include "ruby.h"
>   2: 
>   3: int main() {return 0;}
>   /* end */

Comment: Did you open XCode after installation and accept its license agreement? Did you install the `Command Line Developer Tools`?

Comment: @spickermann You mean x-code? If so, yes already did that.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're either missing the XCode command line tools:

`xcode-select --install`

Or mySQL packages:
If you don't already have homebrew:

`$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Then to install mysql:

`brew install mysql`

I can't remember which solved this issue for me in the past but I'm sure it was one of them.

Comment: mysql has been installed with success via homebrew but still the gem mysql2 returns the error i mentioned above.

Comment: @HaCos that could be because Ruby needs the header files (found in the development toolkit) to install the gem. Homebrew can install mysql without those header files. Definitely should run the `xcode-select install` command if you haven't already

Comment: @JayDorsey mysql is already installed with success via homebrew.

Comment: After, `xcode-select --install`, open Xcode, and install "Additional Components", restart computer, open `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages` and there will be a file `macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg`. Open that.

Answer (score 0):

Cross linking my answer to almost this exact same question. I think it might just be not finding the correct config path

`sudo gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config`

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53199274/cannot-execute-mysql-config-at-usr-local-bin-mysql-config/53202584#53202584)

edit: formatting

Comment: It returns:
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
 mysql2 requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.

Comment: sounds like you either need to downgrade the gem to a version that supports < ruby 2.0, or upgrade to ruby 2.0. Personally I'm using 2.4.4 on my current project.

Comment: I try gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.17' --source 'http://rubygems.org/' but i receive: Building native extensions. This could take a while... ERROR: Error installing mysql2: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb checking for ruby/thread.h... *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options. I updated my initial post with mkmf.log content.