# ERROR : while trying to install mysql2 -v '0.3.21' on ubuntu 20.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-20.04, mysql-5.7, mysql2, mysql2psql-gem

When i am trying to do bundle install getting following error

```
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.21), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.21' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I am working on Ubuntu 20.4 full error i am getting is

```
Fetching mysql2 0.3.21
Installing mysql2 0.3.21 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/tanuja/.rbenv/versions/2.2.10/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20210316-16230-vpblwe.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
-----
libmysqlclient is missing. Trying again with extra runtime libraries...
-----
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
-----
libmysqlclient is missing. You may need to 'apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev' or 'yum install mysql-devel', and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/tanuja/.rbenv/versions/2.2.10/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/tanuja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.10/gems/mysql2-0.3.21 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/tanuja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.10/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.3.21/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.21), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.21' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
```

I tried many things from related post,like installation of libmysqlclient-dev but didn't work.

If anyone can help please. Thank You !

Comment: It says in that trace you need to install: `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: @razvans thanks for the reply, but it is not working getting same error at the time of bundle install.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167598/mysql-install-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension?rq=1

Comment: @razvans Actually i am using Ubuntu 20.4 so i tried what you sent first but didn't work.

Comment: Does this work: `apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient-dev`?

Comment: @razvans no its not working..