# OS X Mountain Lion: gcc-4.2 No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, gcc, rubygems, makefile, osx-mountain-lion

Tried to install a gem on Mountain Lion and make couldn't find gcc-4.2:

```
kamil$ gem install posix-spawn -v '0.3.6'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing posix-spawn:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/kamil/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling posix-spawn.c
make: gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [posix-spawn.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If you have Xcode installed, gcc should be available. Check where it is with:

```
kamil$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Then make a user-land symbolic link from gcc-4.2 to plain gcc:

```
kamil$ sudo ln -s ~/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

(Ensure the user-land bind folder is in your path via `export PATH=...:$HOME/bin` in your `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc`.)

Gem installed fine afterwards.

Comment: It boggles my mind why this isn't set by default when you install Command Line Tools. I've spent so much time trying to get this work and finally came across your answer. Is this a Ruby issue or an Xcode issue where these operations fail even with gcc installed?

Comment: If you get a 'permission denied' error when you try to run 'ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2'

1) run 'sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/gcc'
2) run 'sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2'

Comment: The problem with this is that the gcc version may not actually be 4.2. It'll function as a work around but this seems like a really hacky solution. It'd probably be better to actually install the correct version of gcc with homebrew as @Piioo suggests.

Comment: This will not work with any modern OSX version due to `System Integrity Protection`.

Comment: @fivenp thanks, I updated my answer to create the symlink in user-land as you recommended in your answer.

Comment: I don't think the updated answer works. My solutions is 
`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2`

Comment: @Mr.Ronald although I can make a link in `/usr/local/bin`, this is not picked up in the installation process I'm following (doing a `pip install`), although `which gcc-4.2` shows the link in `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 14):

Install simply apple-gcc42 with brew. It generate gcc-4.2 .

```
brew install apple-gcc42
```

So we do not need symlinks, which apple update may remove.

[Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

Comment: Brew tells me `Error: No available formula with the name "apple-gcc42" `

Answer (score 1):

As @Artur Bodera mentioned modern OSX will refuse to let you create the symlink in the systems /bin folder.

To avoid this simply create the symlink to your users bin folder

```
ln -s ~/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Don't forget to add the bin folder to your .zshrc or .bash_profile - e.g.

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/bin
```

Comment: the first command gives me a - operation not permitted. and presently my .bash_profile has - export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH". Would updating it be safe?
I am on OSX 10.12.4

Comment: Apples System Integrity Protection from newer MacOS versions doesn't let you symlink to /usr/bin but /usr/local/bin works.
`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while installing a python pip package (building a wheel failed). I got the similar message:

```
unable to execute '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2': No such file or directory
  error: command '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Linking `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2` to `/usr/bin/gcc` was not possible due to Apples System Integrity Protection (SIP), and linking it to `/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2` was not picked up by the wheel building process; it was still trying to use `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2`.

I was finally able to solve this by setting the `CC` variable in the terminal:

```
CC=/usr/bin/gcc
# Install your packages
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

PS : note that disabling SIP doesn't work, even with SIP disabled I wasn't able to create the `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2` link.