# How to install rails mac OSX Mountain Lion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, rvm, homebrew

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OS X Mountain Lion: gcc-4.2 No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256616/os-x-mountain-lion-gcc-4-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

I'm facing a problem to install rails on my MAC.

I'm learning RoR by myself but I can't install rails.

This is what I did:
1 - Installed XCode and downloaded 'Command Line Tools'

2 - Installed RVM with this code:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

3 - Installed HomeBrew and libksba:

```
ruby <(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)

brew install libksba
```

4 - Installed Ruby with RVM (RVM command only worked after I restarted the system):

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

5 - Defined Ruby 1.9.3 as default:

```
rvm --default 1.9.3
```

6 - Now I'm trying to run this code:

```
gem install rails
```

But it returns this error:

> Guerreiro:~ rguerreiro$ gem install rails
>   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   ERROR:  Error installing rails:
>       ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>    /Users/rguerreiro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
> ```
>
> creating Makefile
>
> make
>   compiling generator.c
>   make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
>   make: *** [generator.o] Error 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /Users/rguerreiro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/json-1.7.5 for inspection.
>   Results logged to /Users/rguerreiro/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

Comment: Check out the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12256616/os-x-mountain-lion-gcc-4-2-no-such-file-or-directory): verify your XCode and gcc setup.

Comment: YEAH!!! It worked!!! Really really thanks! Please, post it like an answer, so I can mark as solution!

Answer (score 0):

RVM supports multiple rubies of different versions and hence is preferred for RoR development.
checkout the installation steps at https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Comment: Ok, I runned this command:
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
Is this the command to install rails?

Comment: check the rails installation steps for OSX at http://railsinstaller.org/#osx

Answer (score 0):

did you read `rvm requirements`? it will tell you how to get osx-gcc-installer - install it and it should move to next step.